# grep/ack -o with characters of context (not lines)

Tags: grep, filtering, ack

I'm trying to find a way to

`grep -o "somepattern"`

which gives me something like

```
html/file.js
2:somepattern
5:somepattern
```

but what would be really nice is to have a few characters (maybe 20) before and/or after that match.

I know there is a way to show lines before and after (context), but is there any way to show  context by characters? e.g.

```
html/file.js
2:function helloWorld(somepattern) {
5:    var foo = somepattern;
```

The reason I ask is that if I grep recursively and hit a minified file with a match, it prints the entire file, which is super annoying.

Comment: The real solution is to be able to ignore minified Javascript, and that's coming in ack 2.0.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grep characters before and after match?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8101701/grep-characters-before-and-after-match)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### Using [`ack`](http://betterthangrep.com/):

```
% ack -o '.{0,10}string.{0,10}' | head
cli/cmdlineparser.cpp:22:#include <string>
cli/cmdlineparser.cpp:23:include <cstring>
cli/cmdlineparser.cpp:37:onst std::string& FileList
ctor<std::string>& PathNam
cli/cmdlineparser.cpp:57:     std::string FileName;
cli/cmdlineparser.cpp:66:onst std::string& FileList
list<std::string>& PathNam
cli/cmdlineparser.cpp:72:     std::string PathName;
cli/cmdlineparser.cpp:92:onst std::string &message)
cli/cmdlineparser.cpp:133:onst std::string errmsg =
```

### Using (Gnu) [`grep`](http://www.gnu.org/s/grep/manual/grep.html):

```
% grep -no '.\{0,10\}string.\{0,10\}' **/*.[ch]* | head
cli/cmdlineparser.cpp:22:#include <string>
cli/cmdlineparser.cpp:23:include <cstring>
cli/cmdlineparser.cpp:37:onst std::string& FileList
ctor<std::string>& PathNam
cli/cmdlineparser.cpp:57:     std::string FileName;
cli/cmdlineparser.cpp:66:onst std::string& FileList
list<std::string>& PathNam
cli/cmdlineparser.cpp:72:     std::string PathName;
cli/cmdlineparser.cpp:92:onst std::string &message)
cli/cmdlineparser.cpp:133:onst std::string errmsg =
```

...shows up to 10 characters before and 10 characters after 'string'... (assuming they're there).

I'm using [`| head`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/head/) here merely to limit the output to 10 lines for clarity.

Comment: not sure why you updated it to pipe into head. what you had before (
`ack -o '.{0,20}string.{0,20}'` ) did the trick. Thanks

Comment: Thats awesome Thanks! Now if only there was a way to preserve the highlighting