# Grep characters before and after match?

Tags: bash, grep

Using this:

```
grep -A1 -B1 "test_pattern" file
```

will produce one line before and after the matched pattern in the file. Is there a way to display not lines but a specified number of characters?

The lines in my file are pretty big so I am not interested in printing the entire line but rather only observe the match in context. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: Duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/163726 Near duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/2034799

Answer (score 284, accepted):

3 characters before and 4 characters after

```
$> echo "some123_string_and_another" | grep -o -P '.{0,3}string.{0,4}'
23_string_and
```

Comment: A good answer for small amounts of data, but it starts getting slow when you are matching >100 characters - e.g. in my giant xml file, I want {1,200} before and after, and it is too slow to use.

Comment: The awk version by @amit_g is much faster.

Comment: Not available on Mac OSX, so really this is not a widely available solution. The -E version (listed below) is a better solution.

What is -P? Read on ... 

 -P, --perl-regexp
Interpret PATTERN as a Perl regular expression (PCRE, see below).  This is highly experimental and grep -P may warn of unimplemented features.

Comment: Inexplicably, for me, this prints a certain number of lines of beautiful output, then says "Aborted", every time the same number of lines, which depends on what I'm searching for, but is never the full number of matches, by far.  bash  4.1.2(1) and grep 2.6.3, CentOS 6.5.

Comment: The -E version below does not have this trouble, for some reason.  Also, if I search for something that doesn't exist, I get only the `Aborted` line.

Comment: On OSX install via: `brew install homebrew/dupes/grep` and run it as `ggrep`.

Comment: As implied by @Benubird this will be performance-wise impossible to use for huge files with moderately wide surroundings desired for the match target.

Comment: not working for me    bash-5.1$ echo "some123_string_and_another" | grep -o -P '.{0,3}string.{0,4}'
grep: unrecognized option: P

Comment: Thank you for this!  I wrote a quick script "grep_4CharsSurroundingResults.sh" so I never forget again :)  (Sorry for formatting)   #!/bin/bash   grep -o -P '.{0,3}'$1'.{0,4}' $2
'''

Answer (score 175):

```
grep -E -o ".{0,5}test_pattern.{0,5}" test.txt
```

This will match up to 5 characters before and after your pattern. The -o switch tells grep to only show the match and -E to use an extended regular expression. Make sure to put the quotes around your expression, else it might be interpreted by the shell.

Comment: Good answer, interesting that it's capped at 2^8-1 for length in the {} so `{0,255}` works `{0,256}` gives `grep: invalid repetition count(s)`

Comment: This seems to get considerably less performant as I increase the number of matching chars (5 -> 25 ->50), any idea why?

Answer (score 50):

You could use

```
awk '/test_pattern/ {
    match($0, /test_pattern/); print substr($0, RSTART - 10, RLENGTH + 20);
}' file
```

Comment: Works nicely even with somewhat bigger files also

Comment: how can you use this to find multiple matches per line?

Comment: What's the significance of the first number in the curly-bracketed pairs? Like the 0s in "grep -E -o ".{0,5}test_pattern.{0,5}" test.txt "?

Comment: It's really faster but not as accurate as @ekse's answer.

Comment: It's not at all accurate for large files. For a 5.5GB file that I'm sure has millions of matches, this command returned one result.

Answer (score 35):

You mean, like this:

```
grep -o '.\{0,20\}test_pattern.\{0,20\}' file
```

?

That will print up to twenty characters on either side of `test_pattern`. The `\{0,20\}` notation is like `*`, but specifies zero to twenty repetitions instead of zero or more.The `-o` says to show only the match itself, rather than the entire line.

Comment: This command is not working for me: `grep: Invalid content of \{\}`

Comment: @AlexanderPravdin I think he's assuming that grep is is BRE(so, no -E no -P).  `echo zzzabczzzz | grep -o '.\{0,20\}abc.\{0,20\}'`     If it's ERE then the syntax is easier `echo zzzabczzzz | grep -o -E '.{0,20}abc.{0,20}'`  likewise if it's PCRE then it's syntax as with ERE.  `echo zzzabczzzz | grep -o -P '.{0,20}abc.{0,20}'`     You can also do `echo zzzabczzzz | grep -o -P '.abc..'`  adding or removing as many dots as you want

Answer (score 3):

I'll never easily remember these cryptic command modifiers so I took the [top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8101776/6929343) and turned it into a function in my `~/.bashrc` file:

```bash
cgrep() {
    # For files that are arrays 10's of thousands of characters print.
    # Use cpgrep to print 30 characters before and after search pattern.
    if [ $# -eq 2 ] ; then
        # Format was 'cgrep "search string" /path/to/filename'
        grep -o -P ".{0,30}$1.{0,30}" "$2"
    else
        # Format was 'cat /path/to/filename | cgrep "search string"
        grep -o -P ".{0,30}$1.{0,30}"
    fi
} # cgrep()
```

Here's what it looks like in action:

```bash
$ ll /tmp/rick/scp.Mf7UdS/Mf7UdS.Source

-rw-r--r-- 1 rick rick 25780 Jul  3 19:05 /tmp/rick/scp.Mf7UdS/Mf7UdS.Source

$ cat /tmp/rick/scp.Mf7UdS/Mf7UdS.Source | cgrep "Link to iconic"

1:43:30.3540244000 /mnt/e/bin/Link to iconic S -rwxrwxrwx 777 rick 1000 ri

$ cgrep "Link to iconic" /tmp/rick/scp.Mf7UdS/Mf7UdS.Source

1:43:30.3540244000 /mnt/e/bin/Link to iconic S -rwxrwxrwx 777 rick 1000 ri
```

The file in question is one continuous 25K line and it is hopeless to find what you are looking for using regular `grep`.

Notice the two different ways you can call `cgrep` that parallels `grep` method.

There is a "niftier" way of creating the function where "$2" is only passed when set which would save 4 lines of code. I don't have it handy though. Something like `${parm2} $parm2`. If I find it I'll revise the function and this answer.

Answer (score 1):

I personally do something similar to the posted answers.. but since the dot key, like any keyboard key, can be tapped or held down.. and I often don't need a lot of context(if I needed more I might do the lines like grep -C but often like you I don't want lines before and after), so I find it much quicker for entering the command, to just tap the dot key for how many dots / how many characters, if it's a few then tapping the key,  or hold it down for more.

e.g. `echo zzzabczzzz | grep -o '.abc..'`

Will have the abc pattern with one dot before and two after.  ( in regex language, Dot matches any character). Others used dot too but with curly braces to specify repetition.

If I wanted to be strict re between (0 or x) characters and exactly y  characters, then i'd use the curlies.. and -P, as others have done.

There is a setting re whether dot matches new line but you can look into that if it's a concern/interest.

Answer (score 1):

If using ripgreg this is how you would do it:

```
grep -E -o ".{0,5}test_pattern.{0,5}" test.txt
```

Comment: You meant ripgrep, I suppose. I'd like to know, how is it different from grep? Your answer seems to be the exact same answer as ekse, except for the ripgrep specification.

Answer (score 0):

With `gawk` , you can use match function:

```
    x="hey there how are you"
    echo "$x" |awk --re-interval '{match($0,/(.{4})how(.{4})/,a);print a[1],a[2]}'
    ere   are
```

If you are ok with `perl`, more flexible solution : Following will print three characters before the pattern followed by actual pattern and then 5 character after the pattern.

```
echo hey there how are you |perl -lne 'print "$1$2$3" if /(.{3})(there)(.{5})/'
ey there how
```

This can also be applied to words instead of just characters.Following will print one word before the actual matching string.

```
echo hey there how are you |perl -lne 'print $1 if /(\w+) there/'
hey
```

Following will print one word after the pattern:

```
echo hey there how are you |perl -lne 'print $2 if /(\w+) there (\w+)/'
how
```

Following will print one word before the pattern , then the actual word and then one word after the pattern:

```
echo hey there how are you |perl -lne 'print "$1$2$3" if /(\w+)( there )(\w+)/'
hey there how
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use regexp grep for finding + second grep for highlight

```
echo "some123_string_and_another" | grep -o -P '.{0,3}string.{0,4}' | grep string
```

23_string_and

[image]