# search for hex values and return hex value and offset

Tags: python, hex

[Jack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4810063/jack-whitham) helped me last year with [this Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29972507/find-hex-value-in-file-and-grep-the-following-value). It was very usefull. Now I want to use it again, but the output must be in Hex values this time, and it would be very nice to have the offset were the 'needle' is found in the haystack. Is that possible?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import mmap
fd = open("file_to_search", "rb")
needle = "\x35\x5A\x3C\x2F\x74\x69\x6D\x65\x3E"
haystack = mmap.mmap(fd.fileno(), length = 0, access = mmap.ACCESS_READ)
i = haystack.find(needle)
while i >= 0:
    i += len(needle)
    print (haystack[i : i + 28])
    i = haystack.find(needle, i)
```

Comment: python 3? because you'd need to define `needle` as bytes.

Comment: I'm not so familiar with the different, but I can use python 3 if it is necessary...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this with Python 2:

```
import mmap

with open("file_to_search", "rb") as fd:
    needle = "\x35\x5A\x3C\x2F\x74\x69\x6D\x65\x3E"
    needle_len = len(needle)
    haystack = mmap.mmap(fd.fileno(), length=0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)
    offset = haystack.find(needle)
    while offset >= 0:
        hex_string = ''.join(r'\x%02X' % ord(b)
                                for b in haystack[offset: offset+needle_len])
        print('offset: {}, needle: "{}"'.format(offset, hex_string))
        offset += needle_len
        offset = haystack.find(needle, offset)
```

Sample output:

```
offset: 3, needle: "\x35\x5A\x3C\x2F\x74\x69\x6D\x65\x3E"
```

Since the value of `needle` never changes, it seems redundant to display its value every time a match is found.

Comment: hdk: Note: if you want to print the 28 bytes _following_ where the `needle` bytes were found, change the line `hex_string = ''.join(r'\x%02X' % ord(b) for b in haystack[offset+needle_len: offset+needle_len+28])`.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to change is the display, then you need to change the `print` statement. Also, as J-F Fabre mentioned, you'll need to change the search string to a `bytes` object if you are using Python3.

For Python3:

```
needle = b"\x35\x5A\x3C\x2F\x74\x69\x6D\x65\x3E"
...
print ("%08X: "%i, ', '.join("%02X"%(ch) for ch in haystack[i:i+28]))
```

For Python2:

```
print ("%08X: "%i), ', '.join("%02X"%ord(ch) for ch in haystack[i:i+28])
```